# Контрольная сумма

Tags: android

Привет всем! Подскажите пожалуйста, что за цифры и чем можно их вычислить во 2 и 3 строчке? В первой понятно, что это размер в кб.

```
1-<FileSize val="12007" />
2-<IndexFileCRC val="2283049564" />
3-<IndexFileSig val="302d02140a8bc9b65d0968a901344086102e7667fb397bd9021500a148b9fc56e54ea06517ae904743af9d06853bb6" />
```

Я думаю, что это контрольные суммы, если так, то тогда какие?
crc32 выглядит примерно так - 72a267fb
MD5 - c822000d9e6930e0591e3ea56a6d8d21

Comment: Ради всего святого,

* Не оформляйте текст кодом
* Не ставьте пробелы перед знаками препинания

Answer (score 1):

sha1, sha256

Comment: Нет, во 2 строчке - это crc32, в десятичном виде.